# Wordpress - Search results between 2 dates in search.php

Tags: wordpress, search, date-range

I'm trying make custom search results with date range in search.php

I have 1 text input data, and 2 date inputs.

This code filtering all posts by dates. It is ok. But search keyword not working. Is there any way get search results by date range?

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year' => '2018',
                'month' => '9'
            ),
            'inclusive' => true
        ),
        array(
            'before' => array(
                'year' => '2018',
                'month' => '8'
            ),
            'inclusive' => true
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
...
```

I found solution:

```
<?php 
    $s=get_search_query();
    $args = array(
    's' =>$s,
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year' => '2016',
                'month' => '10',
                'day' => '01'

            ),
            'inclusive' => true
        ),
        array(
            'before' => array(
                'year' => '2018',
                'month' => '10',
                'day' => '05'
            ),
            'inclusive' => true
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: You should post your solution as the answer to your question. that will help classify your question as answered and can help others with similar problems.